# Custom modal dropdown in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, dropdown

Can anyone suggest how to do this kind of custom modal dropdown in React Native with an icon. The icon will be changed by clicking and content will be expanded. I looked through react-native-modal-dropdown library. Can anyone show a small demo in order to figure out how to do this kind of modal dropdowns?[image]

Comment: This might help you, https://blog.logrocket.com/building-a-custom-dropdown-menu-component-for-react-e94f02ced4a1/

Comment: Here its done with React, how to convert div, ul, li HTML tags into React Native ? Because by default 'ul' is unorderd list in HTML

Answer (score 0):

If you want a selector with a modal you can try this library `react-native-modal-selector`.

NPM link => https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-modal-selector

Answer (score -1):

```
`<View>
   <ModalDropdown                    
    showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
    options={TypesList.map(p => { return p.title })}
    onSelect={(e, idx) => { 
       this.setState({ CollectOrderType: idx }) }}
    animated={true}/>
  <FontAwesome style={{ position: 'absolute', right:10, top: 14 }} name="caret-down" size={20} color='rgba(0,0,0,.2)' />
</View>`
```